# Computing moving window state (credit rating) probability transition matrices in R

Tags: r, time-series, transition, matrix-multiplication, rolling-computation

I'm trying to compute a moving window transition matrix for credit rating data. My data looks like this but then with 4000+ rows (there are 8 different ratings in the complete dataset). So we have firms (id) and their prior and current credit rating and  at what date this transition took place.

`df <- data.frame(id = c(100,100,98,99,98,98,56,54), date = c(19750102, 19750205, 19750402, 19750609, 19831212, 19840202, 19840704,19861104), priorrating = c("A","BBB","AAA","AAA","AA","A","BB", "D"), currentrating = c("BBB","BB","AA","AAA","A","A","BB","D"))`

I want to compute the transition probability matrices of these ratings as a moving window. I want to shift 6 months intervals by 1 month. So you would get matrices P for intervals [19750102,19750602], [19750202,19750702] and so forth.

For each element (each date) in the different intervals I want to compute the following. There are no ties (so no dates with multiple different transitions).

```
      require(Matrix)
      #Table with transitions between ratings at time t in the interval
      N <- table(df$priorrating,df$currentrating)

      #Getting the number of total exposed firms Y at time t in the interval
      firms <- apply(N,1,sum)
      Y <- sum(firms)

      #Computing the off-diagional elements of matrix dA; the kjth off-diagonal element count the 
      #fraction of transitions from the kth category to the jth category in the number of exposed 
      #firms at time t.
      
      dA <- N/Y

      #Complete matrix dA by adding default row
      dA[6,] <- 0

      #Computing diagonal elements of dA; e, the kth diagonal element counts the fraction of the 
      #exposed firms Y leaving the state at time t
      D <- rep(0,6)
      diag(dA) <- D #setting diagonal to zeros
      diag(N) <- D #setting diagonal of transition count matrix to zero
      outtrans <- apply(N,1,sum) #vector with number of firms leaving each state at time t
      diag(dA) <- -outtrans/Y

      #Finally compute probability matrix P for element i in the interval (time t)
      attributes(dA)$class <- "matrix"
      P <- (diag(6) + dA) #note that there are 8 different ratings in the complete dataset.
```

And finally I want to compute `P.hat` for the entire interval, which would be the P matrix computed above of each element in the interval multiplied by eachother.

So the output would look like a list of matrices P.hat for each interval.

Now, my code above works on the entire sample. But I'm quite unsure how to implement it as a moving window.

PS: Hopefully my question is clear, if not please let me know!

Comment: Please provide a complete reproducible example. The code in the question gives errors when used with the df shown in the question.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Sorry, I think it should work now.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68048963/roll-regression-for-4-years-of-daily-data-which-moves-one-month-ahead-for-each-n/68056822#68056822 for a similar problem.