# Roll regression for 4 years of data which moves one month ahead for each new regression and with NA treatment

Tags: r, for-loop, regression, linear-regression, na

Some time ago, I made a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68048963/roll-regression-for-4-years-of-daily-data-which-moves-one-month-ahead-for-each-n) about a code that permit me to estimate rolling regression taking 4 years for each regression which moves one month ahead for each new estimation. The answer was of a lot of help and I finally reached to make my own code based on the answer. However, my database has a lot of variables that have NAs for many years, so I had to delete those variables in order to avoid the error I was getting because some windows for some variables were full of NAs. My original dataset called "Data_t" is:

[Data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1KppeFSnmFcDd5gpgy85q6mufIN-Z1L41?usp=sharing)

And what I did was:

```
thedata <- Data_t[,which(colMeans(!is.na(Data_t))>0.88)]
```

Then, according to the [answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68048963/roll-regression-for-4-years-of-daily-data-which-moves-one-month-ahead-for-each-n) I applied:

```
library(zoo)

ndata <- data.frame(date = thedata$Fecha, thedata[,2:ncol(thedata)])
w <- 49 # number of trailing months to regress over 
depvars <- colnames(thedata[7:ncol(thedata)])
indep <- c("Mkt","SMB","HML","RMW", "CMA")

reg <- function(ym_, depvar, indep, data, w, ym) {
ok <- ym > ym_ - w/12 & ym <= ym_
fo <- reformulate(indep, depvar)
fm <- lm(fo, data, subset = ok, na.action = na.exclude)
co <- coef(fm)
n <- nobs(fm)
se_sq <- diag(vcov(fm))
fac <- se_sq / (se_sq + sigma(fm)^2)
fac2 <- sigma(fm)^2/(se_sq + sigma(fm)^2)
co= co * fac + co * fac2
c(co, n = n)

}

ym <- as.yearmon(ndata$date)
ym_u <- tail(unique(ym), -(w-1))

L <- Map(function(depvar) {
data.frame(yearmon = ym_u, 
         t(sapply(ym_u, reg, 
                  depvar = depvar, indep = indep, data = ndata, w = w, ym = ym)), 
         check.names = FALSE)
},depvars)

b_data <- dplyr::bind_rows(L, .id = "depvar")
```

HOWEVER I now have been asked not to omit those variables whit NA, but to include their estimation from the year where they have data. I was trying the option to built different data sets but it is so much work and not efficient at all. I would like to know if you can tell me a way to include within the functional code a way to say r to take variables from the year where NAs end and from there to estimate coefficients.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If x is a vector and tt is a a vector of yearmon times the same length as x then 
`ave(x, cycle(tt), FUN = na.locf0)` produces a vector that is the same as x but with
the NA's filled in with the most recent non-NA in that month.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your idea but I do not know if it can help me because more than filling NAs with previous data, I need estimation to be made for those variables with NAs but starting from the year for which those variables start to have data. In that sense, one variable with data from 2008 (the first year of my data is 1996) should have estimations for 2012 january and ahead (as the window of the rolling regression is 4 years)